# Explanation of notation

Tags: complex-analysis, notation

What is meant by the following:

$$J \circ d_{(x,y)}f $$

Where $J$ is a 2 by 2 matrix, f is a function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ ($\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2)$, and x and y are defined by $(x,y) \in \Omega$.

This is part of a question but I cant start with it because I don't understand what they mean by the convolution above.

Any help?

Comment: Maybe [Jacobian matrix](https://books.google.it/books?id=3xBpS-ZKlgsC&pg=PA50) ?

Comment: it is. d(x,y) is the jacobian applied on f, and it's just multiplied by J